# Using rspec the ensure logger is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, mocha.js

I am trying to test a controller in my rails app under a specific condition that should raise an error and log it. I got the raise test working great but I would like to make sure the logger gets called, so far I tried this, but it is not working

```
  it 'logs the error' do
    get 'edit', {:id => 'banana'}
    Logger.any_instance.expects(:error)
  end
```

ps i am using Mocha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out exactly what I wanted, for example:

```
 Rails.logger.expects(:error).with('this error message')
```

Is how you can use mocha to assert that a specific error message is being logged.

Answer (score 10):

With rails 4, the right way to do it is the following

```
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).with("your error message")
```

Answer (score 4):

Using rspec you would write:

```
Rails.logger.should_receive(:error).with("your error message")
```